# Grocery CRUD: Error if insert some javascript as a database fixed input

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables, grocery-crud

I use Grocery CRUD (CodeIgniter) and it has an issue when I insert a javascript as a input text.
Input:

```
<script> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"; </script>
```

In phpmyadmin:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/As4Bk.png (I can't post image)]

after save this record, grocery crud keep showing error popup:
[image]

Comment: I suspect that the quotes in the script are intefering with the parsing of the data. But I'm not sure and I'm not familiar with Grocery CRUD. Looking at the JSON response/HTML that DataTables is evaluating (consider Google Chrome Dev Tools to get this) might help.

Comment: add htmlentities to query insert/update and the error gone. Btw thank you.

Comment: I've made an answer summarising this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this occurs is that the quotes in the script escape the JSON data used to transfer the message.

The asker was able to work around this using HTMLentities to escape the data prior to sending it.